# Possible to tell whether a DNS query is being answered by the HOSTS file?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, hosts-file

Currently using the [`Dns.GetHostEntry` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry.aspx) in our WinForms application, I discovered that some guys trying to bypass our "copy protection" by redirecting lookups to our servers to localhost by changing the IP address in the HOSTS file (i.e. they enter "example.org 127.0.0.1" to redirect our example.org domain).

Now I asked myself whether I somehow might be able to detect whether a looked up IP address comes from the HOSTS file or from a "real" DNS server.

Of course I might be reading and parsing the HOSTS file by myself but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I am not sure whether there is some functionality in C# to do this. Perhaps through WINAPI (via P/INVOKE). Another, admittedly not very elegant approach could be just reading the host file from your program and parse it for entries that map to your domain name :). Anyway, still not a really a copy protection, as it will be easy to patch the domain name in your EXE file to something else (or, slightly less easier, just using a local DNS server for name resolution instead of a modified host file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dns Query Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc982162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can pass to `DnsQuery` with p/invoke allow a `DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE` parameter.

Here's an example, partial credit goes to the [pinvoke.net resource on DnsQuery](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.dnsquery). Note that this only handles the A record type, you'd need to define the other possible [DnsData structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to handle other response types.

```
public static class DnsFuncs
{
    [DllImport("dnsapi", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern int DnsQuery(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref string pszName,
        QueryTypes wType,
        QueryOptions options,
        int aipServers,
        ref IntPtr ppQueryResults,
        int pReserved);

    [DllImport("dnsapi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void DnsRecordListFree(
        IntPtr pRecordList, 
        int FreeType);

    private enum QueryOptions
    {
        DNS_QUERY_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_RESPONSE = 1,
        DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE = 8,
        DNS_QUERY_DONT_RESET_TTL_VALUES = 0x100000,
        DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE = 0x40,
        DNS_QUERY_NO_LOCAL_NAME = 0x20,
        DNS_QUERY_NO_NETBT = 0x80,
        DNS_QUERY_NO_RECURSION = 4,
        DNS_QUERY_NO_WIRE_QUERY = 0x10,
        DNS_QUERY_RESERVED = -16777216,
        DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE = 0x200,
        DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0,
        DNS_QUERY_TREAT_AS_FQDN = 0x1000,
        DNS_QUERY_USE_TCP_ONLY = 2,
        DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY = 0x100
    }

    private enum QueryTypes
    {
        DNS_TYPE_A = 1,
        DNS_TYPE_NS = 2,
        DNS_TYPE_CNAME = 5,
        DNS_TYPE_SOA = 6,
        DNS_TYPE_PTR = 12,
        DNS_TYPE_HINFO = 13,
        DNS_TYPE_MX = 15,
        DNS_TYPE_TXT = 16,
        DNS_TYPE_AAAA = 28
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DNS_RECORD
    {
        public IntPtr pNext;
        public string pName;
        public short wType;
        public short wDataLength;
        public int flags;
        public int dwTtl;
        public int dwReserved;
        public DnsData DATA;
        public short wPreference;
        public short Pad;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DnsData
    {
        public DNS_A_DATA A;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct DNS_A_DATA
    {
        public IP4_ADDRESS IpAddress;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IP4_ADDRESS
    {
        public UInt32 Ip4Addr;
    }

    public static List<string> GetDnsRecords(string domain)
    {
        IntPtr ptr1 = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr ptr2 = IntPtr.Zero;
        DNS_RECORD recDns;
        DNS_A_DATA recA;
        List<string> Results = new List<string>();

        int RtnVal = DnsQuery(
            ref domain,
            QueryTypes.DNS_TYPE_A,
            QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE, 
            0, 
            ref ptr1, 
            0);

        if (RtnVal != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(RtnVal);
        }

        for (ptr2 = ptr1; !ptr2.Equals(IntPtr.Zero); ptr2 = recDns.pNext)
        {
            recDns = (DNS_RECORD)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr2, typeof(DNS_RECORD));
            if (recDns.wType == 1)
            {
                recA = (DNS_A_DATA)recDns.DATA.A;
                string ip = ReverseIPAddr(recA.IpAddress.Ip4Addr);
                Results.Add(ip);
            }
        }

        DnsRecordListFree(ptr2, 0);

        return Results;
    }

    private static string ReverseIPAddr(UInt32 longIP)
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(longIP.ToString());
        byte[] ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
        Array.Reverse(ipBytes);
        string ipAddress = new IPAddress(ipBytes).ToString();
        return ipAddress;
    }
}
```